# How to clear amplify.store()?

Tags: javascript, amplifyjs

I need to clear amplifyjs storage, remove all key-values. Smth similar to localStorage.clear().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs for *amplifyjs* indicate that you can clear (remove) a specific storage key by storing the value `null` to that key:

`amplify.store( "MyKeyName", null );`

We can get all of the current storage key names with: `amplify.store()` and then use *jQuery* `$.each` to go through the list and clear (remove) each of the items currently stored in '*amplifyjs* storage':

```
$.each(amplify.store(), function (storeKey) {
    // Delete the current key from Amplify storage
    amplify.store(storeKey, null);
});
```

You could put this code into a function and call it or use it inline somewhere, but I'd probably add the function to amplifyjs at runtime with something like:

```
amplify.clearStore = function() {
    $.each(amplify.store(), function (storeKey) {
        // Delete the current key from Amplify storage
        amplify.store(storeKey, null);
    });
};
```

and then call that with `amplify.clearStore();`